# Spark SQL - replace nulls with default values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following dataframe schema:

```
root
 |-- firstname: string (nullable = true)
 |-- lastname: string (nullable = true)
 |-- cities: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- postcode: string (nullable = true
```

And my dataframe looks like this:

```
+---------+--------+-----------------------------------+
|firstname|lastname|cities                             |
+---------+--------+-----------------------------------+
|John     |Doe     |[[New York,A000000], [Warsaw,null]]|
|John     |Smith   |[[Berlin,null]]                    |
|John     |null    |[[Paris,null]]                     |
+---------+--------+-----------------------------------+
```

I want to replace all of null values with string "unknown".
When I use na.fill function I get the following dataframe:

```
df.na.fill("unknown").show()

+---------+--------+-----------------------------------+
|firstname|lastname|cities                             |
+---------+--------+-----------------------------------+
|John     |Doe     |[[New York,A000000], [Warsaw,null]]|
|John     |Smith   |[[Berlin,null]]                    |
|John     |unknown |[[Paris,null]]                     |
+---------+--------+-----------------------------------+
```

How can I replace ALL of the null values in dataframe (Including nested arrays)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`na.fill` doesn't fill null elements within a struct field in an array column.  One approach would be to use a UDF as shown below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

case class City(name: String, postcode: String)

val df = Seq(
  ("John", "Doe", Seq(City("New York", "A000000"), City("Warsaw", null))),
  ("John", "Smith", Seq(City("Berlin", null))),
  ("John", null, Seq(City("Paris", null)))
).toDF("firstname", "lastname", "cities")

val defaultStr = "unknown"

def patchNull(default: String) = udf( (s: Seq[Row]) =>
  s.map( r => (r.getAs[String]("name"), r.getAs[String]("postcode")) match {
      case (null, null) => (default, default)
      case (c, null) => (c, default)
      case (null, p) => (default, p)
      case e => e
    }
  ) )

df.
  withColumn( "cities", patchNull(defaultStr)($"cities") ).
  na.fill(defaultStr).
  show(false)
// +---------+--------+--------------------------------------+
// |firstname|lastname|cities                                |
// +---------+--------+--------------------------------------+
// |John     |Doe     |[[New York,A000000], [Warsaw,unknown]]|
// |John     |Smith   |[[Berlin,unknown]]                    |
// |John     |unknown |[[Paris,unknown]]                     |
// +---------+--------+--------------------------------------+
```